# How to use JavaScript in PDF to discern a user's operating system

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I want to build a PDF that is able to detect the operating system of the user that opens it, and thus provide different information based on the OS that the PDF is being accessed from.

I am having quite a bit of trouble figuring out the JS I need to use to accomplish what seems like a simple task. I can't use this because it is a browser variable:

```
let platform = navigator.platform;
```

I know JavaScript pretty well for the web and can figure out most issues, but I am also having trouble figuring out how to use the proper methods in JS for PDF-JS.

So my questions, can someone show me the proper way to access the operating system information in a PDF using JavaScript (because I think that is the only possible way)? And can you please provide some code examples of how I would go about writing into the PDF from code contained within the document?

For example, a user opens the PDF and they are on a Windows/Mac/Linux Device, so it says, "Welcome from Windows/Mac/Linux".

**Update**

Here is the JS using the Adobe API that I have come up with. As I was asking, how do I write to the actual document being opened so I do not have to open a secondary report? There is a Doc object, but the output is not simple text, it is surrounded by some type of colored element.

Here is the report version that works, but opens a secondary document:

```
var rep = new Report();
rep.size = 1.2;
rep.color = color.black;

switch(app.platform.toString()){
    case "WIN":
        rep.writeText("Hello from Windows!");
        break;
    case "MAC":
        rep.writeText("Hello from Mac!");
        break;
    case "UNIX":
        rep.writeText("Hello from Unix!");
        break;
    default:
        rep.writeText("Hello from...maybe solaris?");
        break;
}

// open created report
var docRep = rep.open("welcome.pdf");
docRep.info.Title = "Custom Title";
```

Here is the version that writes to the page but isn't just plain text, and it is editable, which I don't want:

```
var fieldName = "welcome";
var inch = 100;
var fvalue = this.addField(fieldName, "text", 0, [inch*4,inch*5,inch*2,inch*3]);

switch(app.platform.toString()){
    case "WIN":
        fvalue.value = "Hello from Windows!";
        break;
    case "MAC":
        fvalue.value = "Hello from Mac!";
        break;
    case "UNIX":
        fvalue.value = "Hello from Unix!";
        break;
    default:
        fvalue.value = "Hello from...somewhere else";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `app.platform`:

> **platform**
>
> The platform that the script is currently executing on. There are three valid values:
>   - WIN
>   - MAC
>   - UNIX

Reference: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Comment: Can you please look at my latest update and see if you can point me in the direction of a text field that is not editable and has no surrounding colored area? I marked this answer correct without a full answer because my title is asking for exactly what you provided an answer for, and the reference is great!

Comment: Also now "iOS".